# How can I extract productcode and productname for orders using Data loader?

Tags: soql, data-loader, query

I need to extract the productcode and productname from the order object using DL. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to query the OrderItem and not the Order object since the data loader does not support child queries according to the help docs [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.dataLoader.meta/dataLoader/exporting_data.htm?search_text=relationship).  [image]

So your query would look something like:

```
SELECT PricebookEntry.Name, PricebookEntry.ProductCode FROM OrderItem
```